# Emacs theme won't change

Tags: themes

[image]I am trying to change my emacs theme to spacegray because my current one is not the most appealing but when i to `M-x load-theme spacegray` the theme only loads on the line numbers, and when i reload emacs with `c-x c-c` the previous theme comes back again.

Comment: What do you mean by line numbers and could you please provide a screenshot?

Comment: Edited with the screenshot this is what happens when i load the theme and after i reset emacs it goes back to my previous theme

Comment: Have you tried running `M-x disable-theme` ?

Comment: It's not recognising the theme when i try to disable it  have several themes to load none of theme are recognised when i type (load-theme 'solarized-dark t) in init.el it gives me the error: "error: Unable to find theme file for `solarized-dark'"

Comment: Please provide a list of all your installed packages. Use `package-list-packages` (and go down to the bottom) to get this.

Comment: If you have already loaded one theme and you want to replace it, you need to disable the one already loaded. That's what @Trevoke was, I think, trying to get at.

Comment: Please share the parts of your `.emacs` that involve `load`ing or `require`ing anything theme related (the theme in question looks like Solarized I think).  If you have a separate file for your `custom-set-variables`, then share anything there concerning themes.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, and here's how I fixed it:

I opened my init.el file and commented the last line of code:

`'(default ((((class color) (min-colors 4096)) (:foreground "#5f5f5f" :background "#fdfde7")) (((class color) (min-colors 256)) (:foreground "#5f5f5f" :background "#fdfde7")) (((class color) (min-colors 89)) (:foreground "#5f5f5f" :background "#fdfde7")))))`

and add the following code:

`'(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 120 :width normal :foundry "apple" :family "Menlo")))))`

Restart Emacs, and you should be able to change theme.

Comment: Not a great answer, IMO. (1) You don't show the context for that "*last line*" of your init file. (2) I'm guessing that the context is `custom-set-faces`. If so, the comment preceding it warns you explicitly **not to edit it** directly, but to change it using Customize. (3) You don't explain what your answer tries to do, or why.